# Can someone explain this if-loop for a method to delete negatives in a linear list?

Tags: java

this method allows to delete all negatives in a linear list. I marked the if-loop which i don´t understand 100%. 
So this method travers over the whole list. The rest of the code makes total sense. But the only problem i have is why is `head = n.next` when `prev == null` ? 
Is this because there are two "spaces" now and that is not allowed? (two spaces because `prev = null` and `n` must also be null because it jumped in the if loop for a negative)

```
ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode n = head;
    while (n != null) {
        if (n.val < 0) {       
            if (prev == null) {       //this if- loop i don´t understand
                head = n.next;
            }
            else {
                prev.next = n.next;
            }
        }
        else {
            prev=n;
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well if there is no previous element you are currently at the head. That's what's being checked there.

Comment: There is no such thing like an `if`-loop in Java. To your question: if you delete the first element of the list, you need to adjust the head's list.

Comment: Ah ok i understand. So the head points to n.next now. But n must still be removed. I only see that head points somewhere else and no other things or done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `if` is not a loop it is a statement used for conditional branching.

So, starting from `if (n.val < 0)`, you check if the current element is less then zero, if it is you check if the element before the current element is `null`. If it is, that means that your current element is the head of the list, and it's value is less then zero, so you want to delete it. So what you have to do is only make the head of the list the element after the current head.

So the purpose of `if (prev == null){` is to check if the current element (which is less then zero) is the head of the list, so you could know how to remove it.

Moving on, if the current element is not the head of the list, you would just say that the element after the previous one (relative to current) is the one after the current, so the less then zero element is no longer in the list.

Comment: the if itself is not a condition. What you put between the round brackets is the condition

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear to me! Yes if is not a loop it´s a condition.